# print symbol and evaluate it with a macro

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write some code to print a symbol and evaluate the function associated with it in racket

I already managed to achieve this at runtime using eval, but I think this ought to be possible also without using eval.

Eval version:

```
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define (deco-display fun-sym bstr)
  (display (symbol->string fun-sym))
  (display ": ")
  (display (eval `(,fun-sym ,bstr) ns)))
```

example usage:

```
(define (extract-id bstr)  (subbytes bstr  0  8 ))
(deco-display 'extract-id   bstr)
```

I tried:

```
(define (xxx) (display "asdas"))

(define-syntax (print-and-do stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ p) #`(begin (display #'p) (newline) (p))]))
```

but the outcome is not what I expected

```
(print-and-do xxx)
.#<syntax:interactions from an unsaved editor:5:16 xxx>
asdas
```

Comment: Try `(display #''p)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your solution is correct, would you be willing to put it into the solution box so that we can upvote it and you can accept it as the answer?

Comment: @ soegaard

Thanks, I actually updated the solution using your tip

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to people commenting and some more reading I wrapped up 3 working versions:

```
(define-syntax (print-and-do-v1 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ p) #'(begin (display (syntax->datum #'p)) (newline) (p))]))

(define-syntax (print-and-do-v2 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ p) #'(begin (display 'p) (newline) (p))]))

(define-syntax-rule (print-and-do-v3 p)
  (begin (display 'p) (newline) (p)))
```

Comment: You can simplify the printing expression to `(display (quote p))`. The macro substitutes the macro argument (eg, `xxx`) in place of `p`, so the resulting expression is `(display (quote xxx))`, and `(quote xxx)` evaluates to the symbol named `xxx` as usual. You can also write `'` instead of `quote` in the macro template, and it works the same, but I like to write out `quote` in these cases as a hint that the quoted term contains pattern variables. (So it's constant with respect to a single use of the macro, but not constant over all uses of the macro.)

Comment: @Ryan Culpepper Thanks for the comment, this is true, I am updating the last line of **print-and-do** from:


```[(_ p) #`(begin (display (syntax->datum #'p)) (newline) (p))]))```

to 

```[(_ p) #'(begin (display 'p) (newline) (p))]))```